# Invalid value for Attribute Set column (set does not exists?) in rows: 11, 18, 19, 24, 25, 26 in magento import

Tags: magento, import, attributes, set

I am importing products, when i try to import, i got lot of errors, i have fixed everything and file is valid for import, after submit import button, this showing the following error, I have googled and searched through lot of websites i cant find any answers related to the following erorr.

Invalid value for Attribute Set column (set does not exists?) in rows: 11, 18, 19, 24, 25, 26

Let me know what i need to set in attribute_set, i setting up default as value right now,  Please advise.

Comment: post your imported file ... The attribute_set is the imported file must match an attribute set Name in BO. If you're not sure, just export all products from magento and  see how does look like the file

Comment: sku _store _attribute_set _type _category _product_websites cost country_of_manufacture created_at custom_design custom_design_from custom_design_to custom_layout_update delivery_date description
1968 69 Mopar Charger Roadrunner Air Cleaner W/O Tube  default simple Performance Parts/Air Cleaner base $206.70   10/29/2012 7:35     Thu. Nov. 8 and Wed. Nov. 14  " new reproduction 1968 69 Mopar Charger Roadrunner GTX Air Cleaner Kit, This Kit With Out Breather Tube.Fit 1968-69 High-Performance 340, 383 and 440 engines with single 4-bbl,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was stuck with the same problem for quite some time. Here is the oslution your 3rd column ie _attribute_set must be empty. check what is the value in that column in other product and put the same there. it should solve the problem

If you are not sure of that go to Catalog -> Attribute ->Manage attribute sets. check the name of the attribute and put the same in _attribute_set column in the product row

Comment: Do not add signatures to your posts, particularly linking to your site.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you need to copy the attribute set that is used on those lines (11,18 etc) to your new magento.

Comment: Actually am created the magento site and need to import csv files get from magento export format only.  So clarify why this error showing, because am using exported csv file only...,

Comment: Even though you created a new magento, there is still other information that you need to copy from the old server, like the attribute sets, check catalog->attributes->manage attribute sets to see what you need to copy over